# how to read a text file and publish the data

Tags: ros, bagfiles

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to read a file.txt in my home directory and publish the integer value extracted from the file how can i do that can someone help plz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236117/how-to-read-a-text-file-and-publish-the-data/) by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow the tutorial in [Publishers and Subscribers](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) to learn how to publish a message.

After that, follow these simple steps.

Step 1 : Read integers from file and store them in an array / vector

Step 2 : Advertise a publisher to a topic of your preference with message type std_msgs/Int64.msg

```
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Int64>("topic_name", 5);
```

Step 3 : Iterate through your integer array/vector and publish them.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on 2016-06-10**:
thank you for your reply can u plz explain how can i read a file too?

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2016-06-13**:
Reading from a file depends on the programming language and perhaps the platform.

Clear examples are included here : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Good luck! And sorry it took me 4 days to reply. It was a long weekend here in Aus and I took some time away from all my gadgets.